# How to count total number of members of woo-commerce memberships?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce plugin and WooCommerce Memberships plugin on my site.I need to display total no. of members.I have read documentation But din't find any solution for this.So please help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Get total number of user having membership plan active.

Use can as well change the status as you like and can modify the query to get appropriate result.

```
function display_count()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $result = $wpdb->get_results ("SELECT DISTINCT post_author FROM  $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status='wcm-active' and post_type='wc_user_membership'" );
    if($result)
        return count($result);
    return 0;
}
```